# YouTubePlayerSupportFragment within a SlidingDrawer

Tags: android, youtube-api, slidingdrawer

I am trying to place a `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` within a `SlidingDrawer` view. However, when it runs the video is stopped after 1 second and the follow is posted in LogCat:

```
W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI(1778): YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by ViewName{41726520 V.E..... ........ 0,0-720,1038 #7f060040 app:id/drawer}. YouTubePlayerView is completely covered, with the distance in px between each edge of the obscuring view and the YouTubePlayerView being: left: 0, top: 241, right: 0, bottom: 392..
```

The `SlidingDrawer` is opened and the video is completely visible and not obscured. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: I am currently running into issues with this. I am looking into solutions now. Have you found anything?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I was changing the margins of the YouTubePlayerSupportFragment,where the distance was negative until it worked. Not sure why this happens though.

Answer (score 0):

from [ducumentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView) youtube player shoudbe topest element and have minimal size of 200*110 dp. If it is smaller - player will stop. If any view (even invisible) will overlap the youtube player - player will stop